# Wagtailing include a inline panel (one to many) relationship within the site settings

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am looking to extend the site settings for a Wagtail Project so that the admin can add instances where they were published. That will be used to populate several places around the site, but namely the footer.

I feel like my solution below is fairly janky. I seem not to be able to access the setting values in a django template or maybe I am not attacking it the right way. My approach feels like it isn't great here. Any help is appreciated!

```py
class Publication(Orderable):
    page: ParentalKey = ParentalKey("home.PublishedBy", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='publications')
    name: CharField = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url: URLField = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    image: OneToOneField = models.OneToOneField(Image, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
@register_setting
class PublishedBy(BaseGenericSetting, ClusterableModel):
    panels: list[MultiFieldPanel] = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel('publications', label="Publications", min_num=1, max_num=7)
            ]
        )
    ]
```